# Debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

have an Android app in Eclipse. At some breakpoints my debugger stops, at some it doesn't. Where it doesn't I added log output messages, I do see these messages so code is executed. I did the usual things, like restart Eclipse, clean project, new workspace, wiped app from device. What I found on the net is that some other byte code is executed and so the debugger cannot find the breakpoint. But after deleting the app, the bytecode should be the one generated from Eclipse. The breakpoint which is not being used is never getting this little tick mark. It is active and it doesn't have any conditions.

How can I figure out what is happening?

Comment: Are the breakpoints in different threads?

Comment: Are them in a lib project?

Comment: They are not in a lib, they are not in different threads.